# How to Extract the last paragraph tag text in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The html file I'm parsing has multiple `<p>` tags as follow :

```
<p>first text</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>...</p>
<p>my text</p>
```

Here with it prints the the first paragraph text  : `first text`

```
print (soup.find("section", {"id": "posts"}).article.div.p.text)
```

How to print the last one : `my text`

Comment: `.findAll` and select last one?

Comment: It got solved with `find_next_sibling`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find_all` to get all p as a list, get the last element, and then refer its text property

```
soup.find("section", {"id": "posts"}).article.div.find_all('p')[-1].text
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved using `find_next_siblings` method :

for example extracting the forth `<p>` tag

```
l1 = soup.find("section", {"id": "posts"}).article.div.p
l2 = l1.find_next_sibling('p')
l2 = l2.find_next_sibling('p')
l2 = l2.find_next_sibling('p')

print (l2.text)
```